# Symfony json response is returning content twice

Tags: php, json, symfony, http-headers, response

I have been writing an API using Symfony as the backend, a plugin written by a third party is sending certain data to an endpoint, the endpoint is then to return a json encoded response, however following the instructions as set out in the current symfony documaentation(https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html) the return value is displayed twice and the response is not well formed and outputs like string

The original method that I wrote had calls to a database to validate a token, store a bookmark and display the result of the backend process, however when getting down to brass tacks and removing everything but the response building; it is obvious that this is where the problem lies.  The method uses this snippet, though for clarity I have not included the database processing and used the posted values as the return array, the result is the same if it is the post or processed data, the output displays twice.

```
$token = $request->request->get('token');
$bookmark = $request->request->get('bookmark');
$data = ['token' => $token, 'bookmark' => $bookmark];
$response = new Response();
$response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
$response->setContent(json_encode($data));
$response->send();
return $response;
```

What I was expecting was a single json response but what is returned is a double string of the json output

e.g. if I posted these values to the above snippet:

```
token: ksjdbvqpi8e7rqp7evbprb
bookmark: http://www.google.com
```

the return result is

```
    {"token":"ksjdbvqpi8e7rqp7evbprb", "bookmark":"http:\/\/www.google.com"}{"token":"ksjdbvqpi8e7rqp7evbprb", "bookmark":"http:\/\/www.google.com"}
```

when what I was expecting was just

```
{"token":"ksjdbvqpi8e7rqp7evbprb", "bookmark":"http:\/\/www.google.com"}
```

I have no idea at the moment why it is displaying twice, any help is as always appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Remove `$response->send();`.

Comment: As @u_mulder said, you have to remove the `$response->send()` part. You already an response by the controller to symfony. Symfony then do other things an handle the send-command itself, you dont need to do that.

Comment: @u_mulder thank you if you add this as the answer I will mark it as correct, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$response->send();` is the line that should be removed.

As you already return object of class `Response` symfony will take care to **output** this response to browser, you don't need to do it manually with `send()`.