Symfony 7 returns duplicate response
I need some help with a strange problem on Symfony 7.1 that i can not figure out.
I set up locally a Symfony project and run with Symfony build-in server on a MacOS host machine, and works just great
{ 
  "my_response" : [
      {
         "attribute" : "value1"
      },
      {
         "attribute" : "value2"
      }
   ]
}

However, the exact same project on a Windows Host machine (at first place) and eventually deployed to a Linux server online, outputs the following result
{ 
  "my_response" : [
      {
         "attribute" : "value1"
      },
      {
         "attribute" : "value2"
      }
   ]
}
{ 
  "my_response" : [
      {
         "attribute" : "value1"
      },
      {
         "attribute" : "value2"
      }
   ]
}

My controller / action looks like this
#[Route('/pathto/apiresponse', name: 'path_to_api')]
public function apiresponse(ApiResponse $apiResponse): Response
{

  $response = new Response();

  $response->setContent(json_encode($apiResponse->retrieveResponse()));

  $response->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_OK);

  $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  return $response->send();

}

I have already seen this Symfony json response is returning content twice but i believe my case differs somehow, since it has different response on different environments

Any reason for not using new JsonResponse()?

It was a bad call as it turned out. It would have saved me from all this trouble, and investigation.

This question is similar to: Symfony json response is returning content twice. You even didn't  try to delete your $response->send(); as said in this question's answer.

I mentioned in my post that I had already visited the suggested post prior posting here, and although it seemed similar, I believe it differed, since i didn't return the entire response object as mentioned in the related post, but just the $response->send().

I did try the solution and I explained why I believe it differed. I don’t understand why you become hostile.

I figured out what was going on afterall.
Symfony's Response send() method is as follows (ref: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/7.2/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.php )
/**
 * Sends HTTP headers and content.
 *
 * @param bool $flush Whether output buffers should be flushed
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function send(bool $flush = true): static
{
    $this->sendHeaders();
    $this->sendContent();

    if (!$flush) {
        return $this;
    }

    if (\function_exists('fastcgi_finish_request')) {
        fastcgi_finish_request();
    } elseif (\function_exists('litespeed_finish_request')) {
        litespeed_finish_request();
    } elseif (!\in_array(\PHP_SAPI, ['cli', 'phpdbg', 'embed'], true)) {
        static::closeOutputBuffers(0, true);
        flush();
    }

    return $this;
}

My stack had fastcgi_finish_request enabled and had as a result to have the "correct" response output, while on the other environments that wasn't enabled, there was the incident with the duplicate output.
If i had used JsonResponse in the first place i wouldn't have come across this issue.

The same answer as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55608442/symfony-json-response-is-returning-content-twice. You should delete your question and answer as it has no new problem here. You can add your explanation to the problem in the above question as edit to accepted answer or post your own.

How does this answers why on one environment it worked as expected and on other environments it just didn't?

It just says don't use ->send(). In your question you use ->send(). In your answer you just explain why some environments can work even with ->send(). It is not another question and answer. You can write that answer on the original question.

I have explained how it believed it differed and why. I really don’t understand what you are trying to prove here.
